# "Suction" force of an aspiration catheter with varying cross sectional area

Tags: forces, pressure, bernoulli-equation, navier-stokes

Assume there are two catheters:
Catheter A has a constant inner diameter D1, whereas catheter B has an inner diameter D1 at the very tip (distal), but a larger inner diameter D2 in the proximal section
[image]

Question: When a vacuum pump generates the same pressure difference across the catheters and "sucks" a blood clot from the distal tip, let's imagine that the blood clot is connected to a load cell. Would the load cell perceive a greater magnitude of force from catheter B? Or would it be the same as catheter A?

According to a published research (https://jnis.bmj.com/content/11/2/190), maximum suction force increased due to a larger proximal inner section. But I do not understand how that is achieved?
According to Bernoulli's principle, the pressure should be the same at the distal and proximal ends when there exists no fluid flow. I would imagine that the "suction" force (or the push force from within the blood vessel) can only be increased by increasing the pressure difference applied, or by increasing the tip's cross-sectional area. How does changing the proximal area affect the force applied at the tip? Much thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system can be approximated with [Poiseuille's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation):
\begin{equation}
\Delta P=\frac{8\mu LQ}{\pi R^4}
\end{equation}
where $Q$ is the volumetric flow rate through a catheter.
So, for catheters $A$ and $B$ of equal lengths with the same pressure difference ($\Delta P$) between their endpoints,
\begin{equation}
\Delta P = \frac{8\mu (L_1+L_2)Q_A}{\pi R_2^4}=\frac{8\mu L_1 Q_B}{\pi R_1^4}+\frac{8\mu L_2 Q_B}{\pi R_2^4}
\end{equation}
where $R_2$ is the smaller radius, and $R_1$ the larger one. Rearranging, one finds:
\begin{equation}
Q_A=Q_B\left( \frac{L_1}{(L_1+L_2)}\frac{R_2^4}{R_1^4}+\frac{L_2}{L_1+L_2} \right)
\end{equation}
You can check that the quantity inside the brackets is less than 1 (it becomes 1 in the limit $R_2\to R_1$). This implies that $Q_B>Q_A$, i.e. the flow rate of blood through catheter $B$ is greater than that through catheter $A$. This is possible because the pressure gradient along their lengths are different, despite the total pressure difference being equal in both cases.

Intuitively, this also makes sense since a larger cross-sectional area means that there is more "room" for blood to flow. As an analogue, think of e.g. 1 traffic lane opening up into 2 lanes vs only having 1 lane for the entire length of the road.

Comment: Thanks hiccups for the great explanation! I have derived the hagen-poiseuille's equation by a force balance, and I was able to understand that the volumetric flow rate must be greater for catheter B, but I couldn't figure out how the force perceived by the load cell could be greater for catheter B. Could you share any insights if possible?

Comment: @LawlietLaw Maybe think about how pressure would vary along the length of the catheters in both scenarios, keeping in mind that the suction force experienced depends on the difference in pressure between the inside of the cell and the tip of the catheter "right next" to it. (E.g. imagine if you engineered a catheter where all of the pressure drop occurred in the proximal half, with constant pressure in the distal half that connects to the cell. How much suction would you get then?)

Comment: Here's my thought process after seeing your hint, please let me know if it sounds reasonable: the total pressure difference applied in both scenarios is equal, but the pressure gradient in the distal section of catheter B is greater than that in catheter A, due to the presence of a bigger proximal section which contributes a relatively smaller pressure drop. Thus stronger suction. Another way to think about this is the magnitude of viscous wall stress μ (du/dr); since Qb is greater than Qa, fluid velocity in distal section of catheter B must be greater than in A, giving higher viscous stress.

Comment: @LawlietLaw Sounds good to me!